# Using CNN to extract channel network from old maps

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, image-recognition

I am a numerical modeller working on a flow problem. I have developed a channel network simulator to model fluid flow through an irrigation network.

As part of my inputs I have to use old maps (as old as the 18th century at times) and digitise the irrigation network architecture. This is extremely time consuming as my current workflow involves doing this on GIS by hand. I cannot share the true maps, but here is a hand made snippet to illustrate the problem (note the smudges, text, folds, and additional features on it). I was thinking that due to the high contrast between the irrigation canals and the greyish/yellowish background it might be possible to build a simple convolutional neural network which can extract the information I need and populate a 2D array which contain all the node information and how they relate to the line start and end.

Our team has already digitised about 6 or 7 different maps with up to over 10000 channels! I was thinking I could use this data (potentially fragmented and rotated) to train a relatively simple convolutional neural network.

Before getting started I was wondering if you think the approach would work for this type of data and for the amount of training data we have. Also I am unsure how to handle the fact that the output will vary in size as it will depend on how many channels are in the map.Finally, the output doesn't have to be 100% perfect as I can then easily turn my output into a GIS format to verify it and make minor adjustments.

Any advice would be very welcome.

[image]

Comment: Do image segmentation like this, and create a graph with segmented Lines. :https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvHjV.png

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.08414 Also unsupervised image segmentation can be used.

Comment: @canP thanks for the suggestions. Would you be able to provide an answer of how you achieved those yellow lines in the screenshot you shared? That would be most useful!